# MongoDB 3. Проверить существование коллекции

Tags: java, mongodb

В *MongoDB 2* у объекта "база данных" (типа `com.mongodb.DB`) существовал метод `collectionExists`, который проверял существование коллекции с указанным именем. Но в *MongoDB 3* вместо типа `com.mongodb.DB` предлагается использовать тип `com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase`, у которого такого метода нет.

Как в *MongoDB 3* проверить существование коллекции в базе данных?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки существования коллекции в базе данных в случае *MongoDB 3* можно воспользоваться методом `listCollectionNames`, который возвращает итерируемый набор имён коллекций базы данных. Для проверки существования подойдёт следующий достаточно простой метод:

```
/**
 * Проверка существования в базе данных коллекции с указанным именем.
 * 
 * @param db База данных.
 * @param collectionName Имя искомой коллекции.
 * @return {@code true}, если коллекция существует в базе данных
 *         и {@code false} в противном случае.
 */
public static boolean hasCollection(final MongoDatabase db, final String collectionName)
{
    assert db != null;
    assert collectionName != null && !collectionName.isEmpty();

    try (final MongoCursor<String> cursor = db.listCollectionNames().iterator())
    {
        while (cursor.hasNext())
            if (cursor.next().equals(collectionName))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

P.S. Используется конструкция "try с ресурсами", появившаяся в *Java 7*.